# How we can apply the permutation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

We suppose the matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2n\times 2n}$ is in the following form
‎\begin{eqnarray}
‎S=\left(‎
  ‎\begin{array}{cc}‎
    ‎S_1 & S_2  \\‎
    ‎S_2 & S_1  \\‎
  ‎\end{array}‎
‎\right)‎,
‎\end{eqnarray}‎ 
where the matrices $S_1, S_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. How we can apply the permutation matrices (i.e., by multiplying $S$ with the permutation matrices in the left and right sides of $S$) to create the new matrix $S^{'}$ in the following form
\begin{eqnarray}
‎S^{'}=\left(‎
  ‎\begin{array}{cc}‎
    ‎S_1 & S_2  \\‎
    ‎S_1 & S_2  \\‎
  ‎\end{array}‎
‎\right)‎.
‎\end{eqnarray}‎

Answer (score 0):

There can not be block permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $S’=PSQ$.

In fact, the only possibility is 
$$
P = Q = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_n \\
I_n & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
And this doesn’t work.